# Swift NSUserDefaults app crash first time

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

my app crash every time i installed it, but only the first time..

this is my code

```
 var State = save.stringForKey("StateSave")
    var City = save.stringForKey("CitySave")
    var Vehicle = save.stringForKey("ModelNumberSave")
    var ExtensionPeriod = save.stringForKey("ExtensionPeriodChoosed")
    var Location = "Location"


    if ExtensionPeriod == nil {
        var name = ""
        var FieldChoosed: Void = save.setObject(name, forKey: "ExtensionPeriodChoosed")
        save.synchronize()

    }

    save.synchronize()
    var DetailNames = ["\(State!)","\(City!)","\(Location)","\(Vehicle!)","\(ExtensionPeriod!)"]
```

it crash because it say that ExtensionPeriod is nil. so i think it's because of the NSUserDefaults in the if statement. So my first idea was to put save.synchronize which `var save = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` but it didn't work :\

Answer (score 2):

Your app crashes because in this line:

```
var DetailNames = ["\(State!)","\(City!)","\(Location)","\(Vehicle!)","\(ExtensionPeriod!)"]
```

you are using the force unwrap operator. You need to make sure these values aren't `nil` before unwrapping them.

From [The Swift Programming Language: The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html):

> Trying to use ! to access a non-existent optional value triggers a runtime error. Always make sure that an optional contains a non-nil value before using ! to force-unwrap its value.

You can provide default values using the nil coalescing operator:

```
var State = save.stringForKey("StateSave") ?? "Texas"
var City = save.stringForKey("CitySave") ?? "El Paso"
```

As a stylistic note, your instance variables should begin with lowercase letters. Only type names should begin with uppercase letters.

Comment: they are not Nil, the State and City are taken from database there will never be nil

Comment: OK, but ExtensionPeriod is nil.